# psycopg2: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, database, psycopg2

I looked into many stack overflow posts and most of them told that I need to use a `tuple` or a `list` when inserting into `VALUES (%s)`. I tried both lists and tuples, but I am still getting the same error: `not all arguments converted during string formatting`. Here is the code of the function used to insert some data into PostgreSQL database:

```
sql = '''
    INSERT INTO immediate_info (
    bytes_sent,
    bytes_recv,
    packets_sent,
    packets_recv,
    errin,
    errout,
    dropin,
    dropout)
    VALUES (%s);
'''

conn = None

bytes_recv, bytes_sent, packets_sent, packets_recv, errin, errout, dropin, dropout = data

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect('all the connect stuff')
    # create a new cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # execute the INSERT statement
    cur.execute(sql, (bytes_recv, bytes_sent, packets_sent, packets_recv, errin, errout, dropin, dropout,))
    # commit the changes to the database
    conn.commit()
    # close communication with the database
    cur.close()

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:

    print(error)

finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

As I mentioned above, I have tried using lists as well. This time I decided to first unpack the `data` list first, though simply going through the `data` list using indexes (data[0],data[1], and so on) will, in my opinion, lead to the same results.

The `data` contains some network info used to measure the bandwidth of my computer. All of its contents is in `int` format.

Also, if you noticed, the string formatting here is the old one (referring to `VALUES (%s)`). How can the `f`-formatting be used in this case?
And how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: You are passing `duration` in the values but it isn't listed in the `INSERT` columns.  So eight values are expected and you are passing nine.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake in the question itself, not the code. I simply forgot to edit it out.  Now the question is correct, I hope. The problem still persists.

Comment: Then [edit] the question to show the actual code and error.  And be aware, using f-strings (or any other kind of string formatting) is not a secure way to inject values into SQL queries.

Comment: I did edit it out now. Also, what is the better way then? or are comments not the best place to ask about it?

Comment: The way you're doing it - `cursor.execute(sql, (va11, val2...))` is correct.  Are you sure the current code is still giving you `not all arguments converted ...` error?  The numbers of columns and values seems to be equal now

Comment: No, it still returns the same error. Is it possible that python is sending values in a different type that it is supposed to (string instead of integer)? The columns of the database have the 'BIGINT' type as their value types.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been asleep yesterday!  The number of `"%s"` in the vlaues clause must also match the number of columns being inserted, so your code should be `... VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`, assuming you are inserting eight columns.

Comment: You seem to be mixing the `execute` and `execute_values`[Values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=execute_values#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) query string and parameter values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executing `INSERT` statements using `cursor.execute`

- the number of columns being inserted must match the number of placeholders in the `VALUES` clause
- the number of elements in the second argument to `cursor.execute` must match the number of placeholders in the `VALUES` clause

So

```py
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz, quux) VALUES (%s, %s)""", args)
```

is wrong because there are three columns being inserted but only two values placeholders

and

```py
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz, quux) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",
               ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
```

is wrong because the number of values in the second argument does not match the number of placeholders in the `VALUES` clause.